# Swift - How to access index of UITableView after clicking on button in UICollectionView which is in the UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I will repost my question in more detail.

I have a table view which contains some information.

Inside this table view, I have a nested collection view which contains one button for every cell.
Hierarchy and example of app is shown below. The colorful buttons are the buttons in the collection view.

[image][image]

What I'm trying to achieve is I want to get the index of the UITableView row whenever a user clicks on a button inside the collection view. (I need this index to send data regarding the information on the table view row).

Initially, before adding a collection view, I simply had two buttons, and I was easily able to achieve this by using sender tags. However now that I'm using a collection view, I cannot use `.addTarget` for to it, and therefore can't make use of sender tags.

Maybe there's an easy way to do it but I'm a beginner in Swift so there might be something I'm missing.

I thought it would be as easy as declaring a variable in `didSelectRowAt` where the variable would be equal to `indexPath.row`, however `didSelectRowAt` doesn't work for me at all? It doesn't return anything

`homework_history_cell` which contains outlet for the collection view:

```
class homework_history_cell: UITableViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var homeworkMarksCollectionView: UICollectionView!

}
```

`cellForItemAt` method in my view controller file which is used for getting the sender tag of the clicked button:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellHomeworkMark", for: indexPath) as! homework_marks_collection_view_cell
        cell.markButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.markButton.setTitle(self.homeworkMarks[indexPath.row].value, for: .normal)
        cell.markButton.backgroundColor = markColors[indexPath.row % self.homeworkMarks.count]
        cell.markButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(done_pressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        return cell

}
```

`done_pressed` method which sends the index of the table view row (this is the part that I'm stuck at)

```
@objc func done_pressed(sender: UIButton)
{
    evaluateHomework(homeworkIdx: homeworkIndex, operation: self.homeworkMarks[sender.tag].markIdx) // homeworkIndex is the table row index that I want to send when the user clicks on a button in the collection view. this does not work.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add indexPath.row into tablecell

```
class homework_history_cell: UITableViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var homeworkMarksCollectionView: UICollectionView!
   var index: Int = -1
}
```

when you create cell - add value for index

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? homework_history_cell
            cell.index = indexPath.row
            ....
            return cell
        } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }
```

and  now you know index of selected cell in collectionView didSelect

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using closures:

```
class homework_history_cell: UITableViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var homeworkMarksCollectionView: UICollectionView!
   var onCollectionCellTap: (() -> ())?

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
             didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       onCollectionCellTap?()
   }

}
```

Now, in your class with tableView, inside cellForRow, write this:

```
tableCell.onCollectionCellTap = { [weak self] in
    // this will give you the tapped collection view's row
    print(indexPath.row)
}
```